# Biztalk 2009 Host Integration Adapters

Tags: biztalk

I have installed BizTalk 2009, it's working fine.  Then I installed Host Integration Server 2009 from the BizTalk CD.  Now, how do I install or find the BizTalk Adapters that related to Host Integration Services?

When I look for an extra download on Microsoft site, all I see is download the BizTalk 2009 120-day trial.

When I look in BizTalk Admin Console, I just see the "normal" adapters, 
nothing related to HIS.

Thanks,

Neal Walters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue.  I'm at a client site, and the install/iso they gave us 
was the Branch Edition of HIS.  We had to uninstall that, and then install 
the BT Adapters Dev Edition (which apparently includes HIS).

Neal